# polymer load page on-click

Tags: javascript, cordova, polymer, web-component

In Polymer application a have chat-list inside core-scroll-header-panel , where I can see all the dialogs with friends.
I want to load on click chat window with one of them. I also want to pass parameter (friend_id) while loading dialog. What is the correct way to do it? Using core-ajax or some router? And what is the correct way to call it?

chat-list.html:

```
    <core-ajax auto url="http://example.org/app/chat_list" params='{"user_id":"{{userid}}"}' handleAs="json" response="{{response}}">  </core-ajax>

    <template repeat="{{chat in response.chat_list}}">

        <paper-item on-click="{{openChat}}">
            <img src="http://example.org/photo/{{chat.friend_photo}}.jpg"  />
            {{chat.friend_name}}
        </paper-item>

    </template>

</template>

<link href="../styles.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<script>
    Polymer({
        response: null,
        openChat: function(){
           document.querySelector('#t').route = "chat";
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing a single page app, it might be best to do this with a router. The chat window could be an element that you just hide when it's not active. When someone clicks on a friend in the list, it could request the route: `example.com/chat/{friend_id}`, the router could pass the friend id to the window element, and then show the window element.

I personally like to use the `page.js` router and I covered it in [an episode of Polycasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDQqP5Yyczg). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @robdodson ! I've solved it by saving user id in app-globals. Not so elegantly but it works))